# How to stop a span expanding in contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I'm currently writing a Math-Editor that allows me to write special symbols like π or ∆.
This is done by writing `$pi` or `$delta` in a contenteditable container so my Javascript can replace and put in the corresponding mathematical character.
To highlight these symbols I wrap them in a span element for styling purpose.
As an example: π is red, because the span style says so. Everything else is white.

Here my problem:
When writing text after my red π, this text also turns red. I guess it is because I write in the π-span and extend the element by accident.

How could you stop this behaviour? I want the text to return to the default font color. Is there a way to make a span "unexpandable" so the caret is placed *after* the span element?

```js
let editor = document.getElementById("editor");

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (editor.innerText.indexOf("$pi") !== -1) //Fix for IE String.includes
    editor.innerHTML = editor.innerHTML.replace("$pi", "<span class='red'>π</span>");
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
  Sample Text
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code please!!

Comment: @TanDuong Added code snippet. Looks like internet explorer doesn't support `String.includes`...